Is there a way to find "hidden" unused variables in Rust?
The Rust linter is great at picking up unused variables. However, I'm interested in variables, where in certain conditions (release mode, features) aren't used.
A simple example is something like this:
pub struct Thing {
  pub values: [u64; 5],
}

pub fn do_stuff(thing: &mut Thing) {
  let before = thing.clone();
  thing.values[0] = 1;
  tracing::debug!("before: {:?}, after: {:?}", before, thing);
}

In debug mode, we'd like to see the changes in do_stuff. But in production we turn on tracing/release_max_level_warn to avoid a bunch of debug printing (important in performance-critical sections). The linter obviously doesn't mention that before is unused, since in some cases it is used.
Essentially, is that .clone() call eventually optimized out in release builds? Or is there a way to find unused variables like "before" when taking into consideration feature flags?
Here is a benchmark that looks like it doesn't get optimized out (even just as a unused var, none of the feature confusion)? I used a Box so that it couldn't just be a memcopy, but I'm terrible at benchmarks, so I'd love to be wrong here.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Thing {
  pub values: Vec<Box<u64>>,
}

#[inline(never)]
pub fn cloned(thing: &mut Thing) {
  let before = thing.clone();
  thing.values[0] = Box::new(2);
}

#[inline(never)]
pub fn uncloned(thing: &mut Thing) {
  thing.values[0] = Box::new(2);
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::test::Bencher;

    #[bench]
    fn bench_clone_test(b: &mut Bencher) {
      let mut thing = crate::Thing {
        values: vec![Box::new(1); 1000],
      };
    
      b.iter(|| crate::cloned(&mut thing));
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_uncloned_test(b: &mut Bencher) {
      let mut thing = crate::Thing {
        values: vec![Box::new(1); 1000],
      };
    
      b.iter(|| crate::uncloned(&mut thing));
    }
}

Results:
test tests::bench_clone_test    ... bench:      54,280.90 ns/iter (+/- 241.36)
test tests::bench_uncloned_test ... bench:          31.91 ns/iter (+/- 0.39)


The expansion of the tracing::debug macro is insensitive to the release_max_level_warn feature, and therefore the compiler sees that before is always used regardless: its use is however switched on a compile-time evaluated boolean, so is in effect the same as this example.  I believe that, in release mode, the compiler will optimise away the clone in such cases, but I don't think there's any guarantee.

Hmmm, according to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/jj7z7f/optimizing_away_unused_variables/ (old, reddit, etc).  Essentially the compiler is adding a call to Drop::drop(var) at the end of the function, so they're not actually "unused" unless I assume the drop function doesn't do anything (primitives? non-stack?).  Which does line up with my benchmark above.

The clone seems to have been optimized out when I compile the top code when I inspect the assembly (a single mov instruction for the write). However your benchmark code is different and incorporates a Vec (i.e. dynamic memory) that is much harder to optimize out especially since Box (more dynamic memory) is used as well.

Yep.  I specifically used Vec/Box to more mimic what I have in my codebase.  I assume the compiler would do fine (and the performance impact is much lower) with primitive/copy types.

Some relevant discussion from URLO.

Radical idea: you can make your own trace/debug/info macros that wrap the tracing macros in a #[cfg(debug_assertions)] { ... } block. That would trigger an "unused variable" warning on before in the --release profile.

Yep, was just working down this route, and it does look like this is what I want.  Want to make this an "answer" and I'll hit the accept button?  I think my confusion was in the wording on the tracing crate for their features (my mistake, not theirs).  I expected the debug! macro to essentially just expand to nothing when the feature said so, rather than just expanding to an if false {.  I've created a wrapped debug!() that expands to nothing at the appropriate time, and now all the unused vars are properly marked.

The variables passed to tracing::debug! are considered "used" even when disabled by feature because the macro expands to something like this:
if tracing::Level::DEBUG <= tracing::level_filters::STATIC_MAX_LEVEL ... {
    ...
}

which the compiler considers is still used even when the condition is constant.
To really avoid that code being compiled, it needs to be hidden behind a #[cfg] attribute or cfg! macro. This could be done by the tracing macro, but there is an unwritten rule that errors and warnings specific to a profile or target should be avoided.
To get this behavior for yourself, you could make your own macros that proxy to the tracing macros wrapped with #[cfg(debug_assertions)] (which is an imprecise but practical way to detect release builds). Here's that working in action:
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Thing {
    values: [u64; 5],
}

macro_rules! debug {
    ($($args:tt)*) => {
        #[cfg(debug_assertions)] { tracing::debug!($($args)*) }
    };
}

pub fn do_stuff(thing: &mut Thing) {
    let before = thing.clone();
    thing.values[0] = 1;
    debug!("before: {:?}, after: {:?}", before, thing);
}

Building this code with --release will emit a warning:
warning: unused variable: `before`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
13 |     let before = thing.clone();
   |         ^^^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_before`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

